# How to align equations in two places, with no excessive spaces?

Tags: align, alignat

I have three equations I want to align. The equality sign in the first line, with the second equality sign in the second line. And the letter y from the second line, with the same letter in the third one. I don't want there to be additional spaces in the equations.

```
\begin{align*}
    c &= x\\
    d = y + g &= x\\
    e + y \;= \;\,&fffff
\end{align*}
```

This is code that is similar (I added spaces to make it work) to what I want it to look like:

[image]

(Should I give the exact equations I'm trying to align? This is a very simplified version of what I'm trying to do, but it should work identically)

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `\alignat*`, which gives full control on the spacing of alignment columns, and the `\mathrlap` command, from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & & c & =x \\
 d = {}& y+ {}&g &= x \\
 e + {}& y = \mathrlap{fffff}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]